# Remove nulls in pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This *seems* like a straight-forward scenario but I'm stumped ...

I have a table with the following data:

```
IsGood  Reason
------  ------
1       Good One
1       Good Two
0       Bad One
0       Bad Two
0       Bad Three
```

And I want to query it to pivot the data horizontally, like this:

```
GoodReason  BadReason
----------  ---------
Good One    Bad One
Good Two    Bad Three
NULL        Bad Two
```

However the results come out like this:

```
GoodReason  BadReason
----------  ---------
NULL        Bad One
NULL        Bad Three
NULL        Bad Two
Good One    NULL
Good Two    NULL
```

```sql
create table #reasons
(
    IsGood bit,
    Reason nvarchar(20)
)
insert into #reasons 
           ( IsGood,   Reason      )
    values ( 1,        'Good One'  )
         , ( 1,        'Good Two'  )
         , ( 0,        'Bad One'   )
         , ( 0,        'Bad Two'   )
         , ( 0,        'Bad Three' )

select * from #reasons

select 'Attempt #1'
    , case when r.IsGood = 1 then r.Reason else null end GoodReason
    , case when r.IsGood = 0 then r.Reason else null end BadReason
from
    #reasons r
group by r.IsGood, r.Reason

select 'Attempt #2'
    , max(case when r.IsGood = 1 then r.Reason else null end) GoodReason
    , max(case when r.IsGood = 0 then r.Reason else null end) BadReason
from
    #reasons r
group by r.IsGood, r.Reason

drop table #reasons
go
```

The good/bad reasons are driven from the UI and can change, be added to, etc so I've ruled out a PIVOT approach - happy to educated otherwise!.

Repo also available at - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9ebc3/2

How to I get the results without the null values?

Many thanks,

Franz.

Comment: do you want  todisplay blank instead (in place) of null ..??

Comment: Why should 'Good Two' be matched with 'Bad Three' in the expected result?

Comment: The matching isn't required, I'm just giving an indication of the required result @LukStorms

Comment: Ideally, but even my dev sql skills can cope with that :) @Mahesh.K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to generate the sequence number based on *IsGood* and use in `GROUP BY` clause for the derived table

```
select 
      max(case when IsGood = 1 then Reason end) GoodReason,
      max(case when IsGood = 0 then Reason end) BadReason 
from
(
    select *, 
           row_number() over (partition by IsGood order by IsGood) Seq
    from reasons
)a
group by Seq
```